# How to create Dictionary containing the PK from tables

Tags: c#, dictionary, primary-key, business-objects

I want to know how to store the primary keys of table with respective values into a dictionary.

I mean, a table in database called ContactPhone (PK = ID, ContactID, PhoneTypeID)

I would like something like:

```
Dictionary<string, object>
```

String I mean for the primary key of a table an eventually the value would a object reflected that represents the table. When my table has one PK, the dictionary has one string and eventually the object. But if it's a composed table and I need to save many PK to recognize my object. What would be the optimal way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be, declare a `ContactPhone` type and then use it to add as value to the dictionary

```
public class ContactPhone
{
public int ID {get; set);
public int ContactID {get; set;};
public int PhoneTypeID {get; set;};
}

// key is ID, value is the ContactPhone object
Dictionary<int, ContactPhone> contacts = new Dictionary<int, ContactPhone>();

// create a new ContactPhone object
ContactPhone contact = new ContactPhone(1, 1, 1); 
// put the ContactPhone object into the dictionary with ID as the key
contacts.Add(1,contact);
```

Off course you will have to fetch the data and then loop through it to put the data into the dictionary.